# Create an array with a pre determined mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

I am attempting to create an array with a predetermined mean and standard deviation value using Numpy. The array needs random numbers within it.

So far I can produce an array and calculate the mean and std. but can not get the array to be controlled by the values:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(1000)
print("Average:")
mean = x.mean()
print(mean)
print("Standard deviation:")
std = x.std()
print(std)
```

How to control the array values through the mean and std?

Comment: what do you mean by "controlling" the array?  Can you clarify that?

Comment: Start by picking a specific example. How do you suggest selecting a single array of 10 elements with mean 50 and stddev 5? There are an infinite number of such collections.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want a normal distribution, right?

Comment: its not clear what are you trying to achieve. Can you provide more details, please?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, I need to create an array with 1000 random floats however it needs to have the mean = 0.025 and the standard deviation = 0.025

Comment: This does not answer the questions which have been asked: what distributions should entries of your array follow?

Comment: Camilleri, I apologise I am relatively new to this and the requirements I was given was to produce an array with 1000 random floats and the given mean and std. That was all the information given to me for this task. I have to also produce a histogram of the data afterwards in which I assume I will address the distribution.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). If your mean is `my_mean` and your std `my_str`:

```
x = np.random.normal(loc=my_mean, scale=my_std, size=1000)
```

Comment: The answer is incorrect when in this code.
```np.random.normal(1.13, 0.339, 5)```
The array number doesn't correspond to the mean and STD

Answer (score 8):

Another solution, using [`np.random.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html):

```
my_std * np.random.randn(1000) + my_mean
```

Example:

```
my_std = 0.025
my_mean = 0.025

x = my_std * np.random.randn(1000) + my_mean
x.mean()
# 0.025493112966038879
x.std()
# 0.024464870590114995
```

With the same random seed, this actually produces the exact same results as `numpy.random.normal`:

```
np.random.seed(42)
my_std * np.random.randn(5) + my_mean
# array([ 0.03741785,  0.02154339,  0.04119221,  0.06307575,  0.01914617])

np.random.seed(42)
np.random.normal(loc=my_mean, scale=my_std, size=5) #note the size here is 5 now
# array([ 0.03741785,  0.02154339,  0.04119221,  0.06307575,  0.01914617])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the mean and standard deviation, you have two degrees of freedom. This means that you can select random numbers for all but two elements of your array. The last two must be calculated by solving the system of equations given by the formulas for mean and stddev.

Comment: I agree the question is very unclear, but it seems what OP really wanted was an array of gaussian rv's with specified mean and std