# Generating a numpy random see array of 100 random numbers drawn from a normal distribution with mean 1 and standard deviation 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
np.random.seed(my_seed)

from math import *
import numpy as np

A = np.arrange(100)
```

I have this however unsure how to deal with mean of and standard deviation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an array with a pre determined mean and standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177594/create-an-array-with-a-pre-determined-mean-and-standard-deviation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
mu, sigma = 1, 2 # mean and standard deviation
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 100)


#to find Standard Deviation and mean:
x = np.random.randn(100)
mean = x.mean()
std = x.std()
```

Comment: thank you and how do I compute the mean and standard deviation of A.

Comment: if you use x = np.random.randn(100) finding of the mean and standard devation is as follows: mean = x.mean() std = x.std()

Comment: great , how would I transform the array  A into a new array B with shape (10, 10).

Comment: I think I provided your question in detail. All task implementation is not the aim of this portal!